# What is the fastest way to deep comparing two objects in javascript/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I got two big objects in JSON, i'm loading it using fs, parsing it and changing into MAP

```js
let dataPin = fs.readFileSync('pin.json');
let dataTotal = fs.readFileSync('total.json');
let t = JSON.parse(dataTotal);
let p = JSON.parse(dataPin);

let Map1 = new Map()
 for (let entry in t) {
     let key = t[entry]
     Map1.set(key, entry)
 }

 let Map2 = new Map()
  for (let entry in p) {
      let key = p[entry]
      Map2.set(key, entry)
  }
```

Than using two foreach. I have to compare all the values with each other and check if any of them are contained in them.

```
Map1.forEach((i1,p)=>{
  Map2.forEach((i2,t)=>{

    if(t.eventStart==p.timestamp && ( p.home.includes(t.home) || t.home.includes(p.home) || p.away.includes(t.away) || t.away.includes(p.away) )){
   // than do some stuff
 }
 });
});
```

The script needs arround 10 seconds to execute with two 4mb jsons i want to find faster way, is there any? I'm using node.js

Sample of json

```json
[
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"spread",
      "odd":1.5424,
      "selection":"away",
      "points":1.5,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.497"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"spread",
      "odd":2.8437,
      "selection":"home",
      "points":-1.5,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"2.760"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"spread",
      "odd":1.6755,
      "selection":"away",
      "points":1.25,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.628"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"spread",
      "odd":2.4803,
      "selection":"home",
      "points":-1.25,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"2.410"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"spread",
      "odd":1.9,
      "selection":"away",
      "points":1,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.854"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"spread",
      "odd":2.1111,
      "selection":"home",
      "points":-1,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"2.060"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"spread",
      "odd":2.2309,
      "selection":"away",
      "points":0.75,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"2.170"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"spread",
      "odd":1.8124,
      "selection":"home",
      "points":-0.75,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.763"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"spread",
      "odd":2.5611,
      "selection":"away",
      "points":0.5,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"2.490"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"spread",
      "odd":1.6406,
      "selection":"home",
      "points":-0.5,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.595"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":1.2069,
      "selection":"under",
      "points":4.5,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.165"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":5.8326,
      "selection":"over",
      "points":4.5,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"5.630"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":1.4911,
      "selection":"under",
      "points":3.5,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.434"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":3.0363,
      "selection":"over",
      "points":3.5,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"2.920"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":1.5889,
      "selection":"under",
      "points":3.25,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.537"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":2.6981,
      "selection":"over",
      "points":3.25,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"2.610"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":1.7419,
      "selection":"under",
      "points":3,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.684"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":2.348,
      "selection":"over",
      "points":3,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"2.270"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":2,
      "selection":"under",
      "points":2.75,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.943"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":2,
      "selection":"over",
      "points":2.75,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.943"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":2.2565,
      "selection":"under",
      "points":2.5,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"2.180"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":1.7959,
      "selection":"over",
      "points":2.5,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.735"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":2.6818,
      "selection":"under",
      "points":2.25,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"2.590"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":1.5946,
      "selection":"over",
      "points":2.25,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.540"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":4.5028,
      "selection":"under",
      "points":1.5,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"4.340"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"total",
      "odd":1.2855,
      "selection":"over",
      "points":1.5,
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.239"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"moneyline",
      "odd":5.8775,
      "selection":"away",
      "points":"",
      "period":0,
      "payout":"5.700"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"moneyline",
      "odd":1.6519,
      "selection":"home",
      "points":"",
      "period":0,
      "payout":"1.602"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"moneyline",
      "odd":4.4545,
      "selection":"draw",
      "points":"",
      "period":0,
      "payout":"4.320"
   },
   {
      "home":"legia warsaw",
      "away":"cracovia krakow",
      "sportID":29,
      "timestamp":1602267300000,
      "eventID":1186957014,
      "eventName":"legia warsaw - cracovia krakow",
      "type":"spread",
      "odd":1.5158,
      "selection":"away",
      "points":0.75,
      "period":1,
      "payout":"1.465"
   }
]
```

Both jsons got "Home/Away" value which is pretty similar, i need to find all records where One of that are included in other one

I also found that foreach using map is faster than loop arround json, that's why i'm changing it into MAP

Comment: so the 2 jsons don't have the same properties?

Comment: Please share a sample of the 2 objects and the expected output. Why is the conversion from an object to Map required?

Comment: @OmriAttiya I need to check if object1.home.included in object2.home or if object2.home included in object1.home so i can't just change it into string and compare

Comment: In your code above, in your `forEach` loops, you're using `p` and `t` but not `i1` and `i2`. Are you sure that's right? `p` and `t` should each be indexes - numbers - and therefore, `p.home` and `t.eventStart` and all those other things wouldn't exist on those variables...

Comment: @adiga i already shared in the post

Comment: @tkol i1 and i2 are index, p and t are the objects. All is working fine, i'm just looking for a faster way. Maybe i should use other data type than json?

Comment: By the way, your code is not deep compare. You dont check for each object if its exists in the other map, you just check if some values exists in both maps. Are you aware of that? Is this what you want?

Comment: @OmriAttiya Yeah, you are right, I just need to find values which this condition: 
if map1.home are included in map2.home or vice versa
or map1.away are included in map2.away or vice versa

Comment: @OmriAttiya Is there any way to do it faster? I was reading about json to parquet but im not sure if it will be better, i just want to save some seconds

Answer (score 0):

Here I separated the `home`s and `away` to `Set`s, than check if the sets are identical.
I think that this approach will be faster since it doesn't iterate over `O(n^2)` values.

Check it

```js
let map1Homes = new Set(Map1.map(p => p.home));
let map2Homes = new Set(Map2.map(p => p.home));
let map1Away = new Set(Map1.map(p => p.away));
let map2Away = new Set(Map2.map(p => p.away));

function eqSet(as, bs) {
  if (as.size !== bs.size) return false;
  for (let a of as)
    if (!bs.has(a)) return false;
  return true;
}

if (eqSet(map1Homes, map2Homes) && eqSet(map1Away, map2Away))
  console.log("homes and away are identical");
```

Comment: The problem is i can't check if the home / away are identical, i have to check if 
Map1.home are included in Map2.home or vice versa
or 
Map1.away are included in Map2.away
Do you have any idea?

Comment: You propably don't understand the problem
I got 10000 records in map1  and 10000 records in map2
The first record of map1 home is "Real madrid" and away is "Barcelona"
I want to check all records in map2 and check if Real madrid is included in map2 home or map2 home are included in Real madrid, it's beacuse there are different names some time, for example: There might be "Barcelona" in map1 and "FC Barcelona" in map2
so if i check it by include it will return the value
@omriAttiya

Comment: @KamilZachradnik so it's again not deep compare.. You have to normalize your data somehow if you want it to be easier to compare